# Post ID doesn't Work in Form

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I have a post where I define a new database entity. After user enters needed values and submits the form, I insert the entity and post it back to the same page and display it's ID. When I enter the ID area `disabled` and `readonly` as below, it works perfectly.

```
@using (Html.BeginForm()) {
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)
    <fieldset>

    ID:
    @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.ID, new { disabled = "disabled", @readonly = "readonly" })

    <p><input type="submit" name="submit" value="Create" /></p>
    </fieldset>
}
```

However, when I enter it only `readonly` as in below, it does insert the entity, but doesn't view the ID.

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.ID, new { @readonly = "readonly" })
```

I have another submit in the form, which uses the entities ID. However, I cannot use `disabled` here with the ID area, as it doesn't post the ID value. What can I do to resolve the issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using html extensions, I directly wrote:

```
<input type="text" name="ID" value="@Model.ID" readonly />
```

And it works like a charm.

Answer (score 1):

You can enable the `disabled` field just before submitting. So, keep the ID field disabled.  Now, enable it on submit. ie; if you submit the form on "myButton" click, add this in `document.ready()`:

```
$('#myButton').click(function(e)
{
    e.preventDefault();
    $("#ID").removeAttr('disabled');
    $('form').submit();
});
```

Comment: Thanks and +1 for your answer.