# how to apply custom attribute on Html.TextBoxFor

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-3

I have a jquery custom attribute to mask textbox which I can apply on thml Input control like this

```
<input data-inputmask="'mask': '9.99 %', 'repeat': 1, 'greedy' : true" />
```

but I need to apply it on @Html.TextBoxFor

```
for (int i = 0; i < Model.PurchaseContract.Particulars.Count; i++)
{
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.PurchaseContract.Particulars[i].StandardReceived, new { @class = "textbox", @style = "width:94%;" })
}
```

please suggest me how can I do it

Comment: have you tried new { @data-inputmask = "'mask': '9.99 %', 'repeat': 1, 'greedy' : true" } ?

Comment: @Ismet Alkan : yes but it does not work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't always have to stick with `Html Extensions`, there have been many times I have written html directly instead. Html Extensions make it hard to work with some attributes sometimes, like [in my question and answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15828078/post-id-doesnt-work-in-form).

You can try something like this, but please note I don't guarantee working.

```
@for (int i = 0; i < Model.PurchaseContract.Particulars.Count; i++)
{
    <input type="text" class="textbox" style="width:94%;" 
           data-inputmask="'mask': '9.99 %', 'repeat': 1, 'greedy' : true"
           name="@Model.PurchaseContract.Particulars[i].StandardReceived"
           id="@Model.PurchaseContract.Particulars[i].StandardReceived" />
}
```

Properly named elements like this will work and participate in your Model object sent to your controller.

To provide the exact output with the `Html.TextBoxFor`, first run the project with your current Html extension. Detect the element in the browser and copy the input line to your view. Change it's `name` and `id` with those in the code lines below and add your `data-inputmask` attribute to it.

Comment: your this solution { @data-inputmask = "'mask': '9.99 %', 'repeat': 1, 'greedy' : true" } works fine first time when page load first time, but when I load section where this text box placed by  devexpress callback panel mask feature stop working .. do you have any idea ?

Comment: I got it, actually I have to call this jquery method on end callback js event

    $(":input").inputmask();